# Unable to extend and use a HashMap in Java

Tags: java, extends

I am trying to extend the HashMap class from Java to provide my own version of **get()** method as below:

```
public class MyRecord extends HashMap<String, String>{
    public MyRecord(String k, String v){
        super();
    }

    public MyRecord(Map t) {
        super(t);
    }

    public String getVal(String key) {
        return this.get(key);
    }
}
```

But when I use it as below I get error: **type MyRecord does not take parameters**

```
ArrayList<MyRecord<String, String>> dataList = new ArrayList<MyRecord<String, String>>();
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Because type `MyRecord` does not have any parameter and you have passed it in constructor `MyRecord<String, String>`

Comment: read this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html you might be looking for `MyRecord<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V>`

Answer (score 1):

`MyRecord` only accepts String, it does not accept parameters.

Use the following:
`ArrayList<MyRecord> dataList = new ArrayList<MyRecord>();`

If you want to make `MyRecord` generic, you might use 
`class MyRecord<K,V> extends HashMap<String, String> {...`

Answer (score 0):

`MyRecord` indeed has no generic parameters.

Just by inheriting from a generic class doesn't mean the subclass has to be generic as well. In this case, `MyRecord` inherits from `HashMap<String, String>`. It doesn't have any generic parameters. What does, say, `MyRecord<Integer, Object>` even mean? The kind of map that `MyRecord` is constant - `HashMap<String, String>`. So there is no point i making it have any generic parameters.

So this will compile fine:

```
ArrayList<MyRecord> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
```

If you do want generic parameters on `MyRecord`, then don't say it inherits from `HashMap<String, String>` because then you are limiting it to only be a `HashMap<String, String>`. You can do this instead:

```
class MyRecord<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> { ... }
```

Now with the proper `<K, V>` syntax at the class declaration, `MyRecord` is now generic.

However, your `MyRecord` does almost the same exact thing as `HashMap<String, String>`, maybe you should consider creating a class that contains an instance of `HashMap<String, String>` instead of inheriting from it?

This post might be helpful too: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/246277/good-or-bad-practice-to-mask-java-collections-with-meaningful-class-names

Answer (score 0):

Actually you don't need to pass Template Argument in your custom class
You directly can create object like:

```
ArrayList<MyRecord> dataList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Because you have already passed it hard coded while extension.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your MyRecord class also generic as below:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class MyRecord<K, V> extends HashMap<K, V> {
    public MyRecord(String k, String v) {
        super();
    }

    public MyRecord(Map t) {
        super(t);
    }

    public V getVal(K key) {
        return this.get(key);
    }
}
```

Then it will work for your statement:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MyRecordRunner {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<MyRecord<String, String>> dataList = new ArrayList<MyRecord<String, String>>();
    }
}
```